# What is meant by the classpath root when the classpath contains many directories?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classpath

[The spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) says that it looks in the classpath root for application.properties. I'm trying to figure out what my classpath root is, but when I print the classpath it contains many directories separated by colons.
I gather that all of these directories are searched for loading classes.

Does that mean that a file in any of them will be considered to be in the classpath root? What if there are files with the same name in two of these directories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your situation there are actually multiple class path roots.  Each component of your classpath is a classpath root. So for example if you had classpath of:

```
/user/home/dir1:/user/home/dir2
```

Both dir1 and dir2 would be classpath roots and you could put your application.properties in either place and Spring Boot would find it.

Comment: To complement the answer, if such a file is present in `dir1` and `dir2` in the example above, the first one in the list will win (i.e. `dir1`).

Answer (score 0):

What spring meant here is that it has some default location/s where it will look for the resource/s according to priority.

According to [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) the priority looks like below :

```
file:./custom-config/
classpath:custom-config/
file:./config/
file:./
classpath:/config/
classpath:/
```

Comment: That answer is inaccurate. It doesn't answer the original question and `custom-config` is just an example that requires additional configuration.